# Evaluate using complex integration: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)(x^2+9)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, complex-integration

> Evaluate $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)(x^2+9)}$$

Firsly I found the residues of this function:

$$Res(i)=-i/16$$

$$Res(-i)=i/16$$

$$Res(3i)=i/48$$

$$Res(-3i)=-i/48$$

I then closed the contour using the upper half semi circle $C$, parametrized by $Rz^{it}$ where $0\leq t\leq \pi$ and $R$ is radius, which I'll take to infinity.

Using partial fractions:

$$\frac{1}{(z^2+1)(z^2+9)}=\frac{1}{8(z^2+1)}-\frac{1}{8(z^2+9)}$$

**ML Lemma**(I think) gives me that this integral is $\leq \pi R / (R^2-1)$ and $\leq \pi R / (R^2-9)$

But then the residue theorem:

$2\pi i (i/16+i/48)$ is negative. What is my mistake?

Comment: Look more closely at your own working!!!!  The $i/16$ in the last line should be $-i/16$.

Comment: @David Arghh thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since complex integration and I do not get along,
I would just do this
with real integration.
I know that this isn't
what the OP asked for,
but it can be useful
to solve a problem
in more than one way.

$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}
=  \frac1{a}\arctan(\frac{x}{a})|_0^{\infty}
=  \frac{\pi}{2a}
$,
so
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}
=  \frac{\pi}{a}
$.

Using your partial fraction decomposition of
$\frac{1}{(z^2+1)(z^2+9)}
=\frac1{8}(\frac{1}{z^2+1}-\frac{1}{z^2+9})
$,
I get
$\frac{\pi}{8}(1-\frac1{3})
=\frac{\pi}{12}
$.

Note that
$ \int \frac{dx}{x^2-a^2} 
= -\frac1{a}(\tanh^{-1}(x/a))
$.

Answer (score 3):

$f(z) = \dfrac{1}{(z+i)(z-i)(z+3i)(z-3i)}$

$\dfrac{f(i)}{(z-i)} =\dfrac{1}{(2i)(4i)(-2i)} = \dfrac{1}{16i}$

$\dfrac{f(3i)}{(z-3i)} =\dfrac{1}{(2i)(4i)(6i)} = -\dfrac{1}{48i}$

$2\pi i(\dfrac{1}{16i} - \dfrac{1}{48i})= \dfrac{\pi}{12}$